# roslib does not exist!

Tags: ros, python, roslib, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ros and am still following the tutorials. I was following "Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (Python)", but when I try to compile the code it shows "ImportError: No module named roslib".

I have ensured that PYTHONPATH contains $ROS_ROOT/core/roslib/src. But when I go to the file system, $ROS_ROOT/core is there, but roslib and src do not exist.

System Information:
Using the fuerte Ubuntu VirtualBox Image.

N.B. ROS_ROOT is /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52101/roslib-does-not-exist!/) by [dptsrk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3957/dptsrk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2013-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually the problem has been resolved now.

I was trying to run the talker.py code like you would normally run python codes. I realized later that you have to call make for it to run.

---

Originally posted by [dptsrk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3957/dptsrk/) with karma: 140 on 2013-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0